# Dispatch a Navigation action

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

**Here are my codes**

```
import { NavigationActions } from "react-navigation"
import { call, put, delay } from "redux-saga/effects"
import { AsyncStorage, Alert } from "react-native"
export function* handleResponse(response) {
    switch (response.status) {
        case 200: {
            console.log('logged by phuognn aaa');
            Alert.alert("404400404040400")
            yield call(NavigationActions.navigate, { routeName: "Auth" })
            return true;
        }
        case 201: {
            console.log('logged by phuognn bbb');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The log line and the alert is run, I want to navigate to the route "Auth" but not working.
Is there any problems with my code?

Comment: Could you share the file where your navigations are defined?

Comment: You're not dispatching that action. In order to do this take a look at [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1439) or [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/153) threads

Answer (score 0):

**Mistake**

```
yield call(NavigationActions.navigate, { routeName: "Auth" })
```

**replace with**

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Auth");
```

here are the links for understanding

(**Moving between screens**)
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating

Comment: Well, the function handleResponse is called from a saga. So there is no props i think

Answer (score 0):

`NavigationActions.navigate` is an action creator function, not an api call or similar. To dispatch actions from inside a saga, you should use `put` instead of `call`.

```
import { NavigationActions } from "react-navigation"
import { call, put, delay } from "redux-saga/effects"
import { AsyncStorage, Alert } from "react-native"
export function* handleResponse(response) {
    switch (response.status) {
        case 200: {
            console.log('logged by phuognn aaa');
            Alert.alert("404400404040400");
            yield put(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "Auth" }));
            return true;
        }
        case 201: {
            console.log('logged by phuognn bbb');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Try this code instead. I'm not too familiar with `redux-saga`. I prefer `redux-observable`, so let me know if this works.